# Hangman 2 for Invent with Python

Tags: python

So I'm working on inventwithpython, and I'm on the hangman 2 chapter. But when the game starts, it's already at the 7th strike hangman picture. I'm not sure where the problem is. Here is my code:

```
import random
HANGMANPICS = ['''

  +---+
  |   |
      |
      |
      |
      |
=========''', '''

  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
      |
      |
      |
=========''', '''

  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
  |   |
      |
      |
=========''', '''

  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|   |
      |
      |
=========''', '''

  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
      |
      |
=========''', '''

  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 /    |
      |
=========''', '''

  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 / \  |
      |
=========''', '''
   +----+
   |    |
  [O    |
  /|\   |
  / \   |
        |
 ==========''', '''
   +----+
   |    |
  [O]   |
  /|\   |
  / \   |
        |
 ==========''']
words = 'ant baboon badger bat bear beaver camel cat clam cobra cougar coyote crow deer dog donkey duck eagle ferret fox frog goat goose hawk lion lizard llama mole monkey moose mouse mule newt otter owl panda parrot pigeon python rabbit ram rat raven rhino salmon seal shark sheep skunk sloth snake spider stork swan tiger toad trout turkey turtle weasel whale wolf wombat zebra'.split()

def getRandomWord(wordList):
    # This function returns a random string from the passed list of strings.
    wordIndex = random.randint(0, len(wordList) - 1)
    return wordList[wordIndex]

def displayBoard(HANGMANPICS, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord):
    print(HANGMANPICS[len(HANGMANPICS) -1])
    print()

    print('Missed letters:', end=' ')
    for letter in missedLetters:
        print(letter, end=' ')
    print()

    blanks = '_' * len(secretWord)

    for i in range(len(secretWord)): # replace blanks with correctly guessed letters
        if secretWord[i] in correctLetters:
            blanks = blanks[:i] + secretWord[i] + blanks[i+1:]

    for letter in blanks: # show the secret word with spaces in between each letter
        print(letter, end=' ')
    print()

def getGuess(alreadyGuessed):
    # Returns the letter the player entered. This function makes sure the player entered a single letter, and not something else.
    while True:
        print('Guess a letter.')
        guess = input()
        guess = guess.lower()
        if len(guess) != 1:
            print('Please enter a single letter.')
        elif guess in alreadyGuessed:
            print('You have already guessed that letter. Choose again.')
        elif guess not in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
            print('Please enter a LETTER.')
        else:
            return guess

def playAgain():
    # This function returns True if the player wants to play again, otherwise it returns False.
    print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
    return input().lower().startswith('y')


print('H A N G M A N')
missedLetters = ''
correctLetters = ''
secretWord = getRandomWord(words)
gameIsDone = False

while True:
    displayBoard(HANGMANPICS, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord)

    # Let the player type in a letter.
    guess = getGuess(missedLetters + correctLetters)

    if guess in secretWord:
        correctLetters = correctLetters + guess

        # Check if the player has won
        foundAllLetters = True
        for i in range(len(secretWord)):
            if secretWord[i] not in correctLetters:
                foundAllLetters = False
                break
        if foundAllLetters:
            print('Yes! The secret word is "' + secretWord + '"! You have won!')
            gameIsDone = True
    else:
        missedLetters = missedLetters + guess

        # Check if player has guessed too many times and lost
        if len(missedLetters) == len(HANGMANPICS) - 1:
            displayBoard(HANGMANPICS, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord)
            print('You have run out of guesses!\nAfter ' + str(len(missedLetters)) + ' missed guesses and ' + str(len(correctLetters)) + ' correct guesses, the word was "' + secretWord + '"')
            gameIsDone = True

    # Ask the player if they want to play again (but only if the game is done).
    if gameIsDone:
        if playAgain():
            missedLetters = ''
            correctLetters = ''
            gameIsDone = False
            secretWord = getRandomWord(words)
        else:
            break
```

(To explain more about my problem:) So when you start the game, the hangman image should be the first picture in HANGMANPICS, but instead, it's the last picture in HANGMANPICS. I do have a feeling the problem in on `print(HANGMANPICS[len(HANGMANPICS) -1])` but may not be there either. All help would be appreciated!

Comment: Well, you feel the problem is with that line. Why do you think that? What did you try to determine what's wrong? What should that print do and when and why?

Comment: Because it's where the picture is printed.

Comment: And it's the code with the hangman part.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's the problem.  You specifically tell it to print the last element of the file.  Instead, use the length of the missed letters list.

```
print(HANGMANPICS[len(missedLetters)])
```

With that change, it seems to work pretty well.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  If you want to know what it does, don't post here -- make the change, run the program, and trace the operation with a debugger or `print` statements.